# Was the word "guy" gender-neutral in the 1930s?

Tags: word-choice, etymology, gender-neutral

I have an attestation from *[The Glass Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Glass_Key)*, by Dashiell Hammett and first published in 1930

> She rubbed her face into the chintz cushion under it and said: “A
>   swell guy I turned out to be, promising to marry him yesterday and
>   then leaving him to take the first tramp I run into home with me.”
>   [source](https://books.google.it/books?id=Z11RBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT27&lpg=PT27&dq=%22swell%20guy%22%20%22promising%20to%20marry%20him%22&source=bl&ots=ZlJYqD1Y4P&sig=NgM__2YFBlM_Ir4j_dZp1gwX2F4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiM7NyF_aLZAhWI6RQKHbeiDHkQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22swell%20guy%22%20%22promising%20to%20marry%20him%22&f=false)

(the "tramp" she's referring to is a man)

This suggests that "guy" in 1930/31 meant "an informal word for person," with no connotations of either "grotesque in appearance" or "male in gender." But all the other usages of "guy" in that book refer to men (as far as I can tell). How confident can I be that "guy" in the 1930s was gender-neutral?

Comment: Considering that the musical *Guys and Dolls* is based on Damon Runyon short stories from the 1930s, and that I can find the quote *"He mistreats my friend in every way any guy ever thought of mistreating a doll, and besides the old established ways of mistreating a doll, Frank thinks up quite a number of new ways, being really quite ingenious in this respect."* in one of these stories, where *guys* really seems to refer to men, I don't think you can be sure at all. Of course, Damon Runyon was from New York, and Dashiell Hammett from California, and I assume slang was more regional back then.

Comment: The quote above is from *Dream Street Rose*, 1932.

Comment: It should be noted that Damon Runyon was well-known to invent his own street slang, so he's not a reliable reference.

Comment: Going back to the 60s, at least, it was not uncommon for "guys" to be used to refer to a mixed-gender group, without irony.  It was also used in that time frame to refer to a group of women, but with a touch of irony.

Comment: I read that example as her ironically applying the idiom _a swell guy_ to herself. I do not conclude that she would refer to herself as a _guy_ in any other context.

Comment: @ColinFine yes, that's my feeling too. But not knowing the author or any of the main characters in the novel, it's difficult to know for certain.

Comment: The only other attestation I found in my "Chandler and Hamett" corpus is from The Long Goodbye (1953, so outside my time window)

> "How about the other guy?" I asked, ignoring him. "What other guy was
> that?" "In the hay, in the guest house. No clothes on. You're not
> saying she had to go down there to play solitaire,"

In that second case, the word "guy" unambiguously refers to a woman, but again it's 20 years too late.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Corpus of Historical American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coha/x3.asp?xx=1&w11=swell&w12=guy&r=) lists only 45 hits for *swell guy*, all referring to men. This, of course, is too small a sample to infer any particular usage with certainty, but it seems to me that the character in question could just as easily have referred to herself ironically as a boy scout: i.e., exhibiting the opposite of various qualities listed in the Boy Scout Oath. *Swell guy* is then a briefly ungendered metaphor for a code of upright, trustworthy behavior — though *swell guys* were not averse to fun.

Given Hammett's hypermasculine style — indeed of the whole genre of hard-boiled detective novels — it's not surprising that a female character would refer to herself with a term usually reserved for men.

When women of that period were  fun, dependable, and trustworthy like *swell guys*, they were likely more often called [*a good egg*](https://www.english-corpora.org/coha/x3.asp?xx=1&w10=good&w11=egg&r=), a term used for both genders.

Singular *[guy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/guy)* is still gendered for most Americans, who would only refer to, say, an injured animal as a "poor guy" if the animal is male or of unknown gender. *Guys* in the plural may be perceived by those who use it as [ungendered, but not in all circumstances.](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/guy#Usage_notes) *You guys* as filling the same second person plural linguistic gap as Southern American *y'all* is more readily seen as an inclusive use.

On balance, I'd say the chances of Hammett's using *swell guy* inclusively are slim to none.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, the history of (this sense of) the word **guy** is short and it starts very clearly with a man: [**Guy Fawkes**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guy_Fawkes#Legacy).  So to start with, the word "guy" as we use it today to refer to a person, most likely a man, is derived from a man's proper first name.

The *OED* definitions are, in order of first-attested date:

> **1806** - An effigy of Guy Fawkes traditionally burnt on the evening of November the Fifth, usually with a display of fireworks.
>
> **1836** -  A person of grotesque appearance, esp. with reference to dress; a ‘fright’.
>
> **1847** - A man, fellow. orig. *U.S.*

My conclusion based on the attestations provided in the *OED* as well as perusal of newspaper corpora is that the word was probably more firmly a reference to men in the 1930s than it is now.

Furthermore, it appears to me from the quote in question that the word "guy" is actually meant to mean, quite literally, a man as distinct from a woman.

> She rubbed her face into the chintz cushion under it and said: “A swell **guy** I turned out to be, **promising to marry** him yesterday **and then leaving** him to take the first **tramp** I run into home with me.”

Here the speaker is ridiculing both men and herself by comparing her behavior to men and describing it as dishonest and unfaithful.  Her use of the word **tramp** refers not to "a person on the tramp" but rather the U.S. slang meaning:

> A sexually promiscuous woman.

These clues all suggest that the word guy here is used to mean a man, in a fashion consistent with the word's historical trend.

Comment: It does not start clearly with Guy Fawkes; of the American usage, the OED specifically only asserts that "The earliest examples may be influenced by sense 2." ("Sense 2" being your 1936 definition.) Given the complete discontinuity between sense 2 and the American usage, as well as the lack of cultural impact that Guy Fawkes has made in the US, it seems much more likely that this is at least largely an independent coinage from the common given name.

Comment: @1006a I think a straightforward reading of the OED text actually suggests that sense 2 developed out of sense 1, which was Guy Fawkes.   In fact, under sense 1, OED offers a note: *The figure is habited in grotesquely ragged and ill-assorted garments **(whence sense 2) [emphasis added]**, and was formerly accompanied by other similar effigies (representing unpopular persons), to which the name of ‘guys’ is often given by extension.*

Comment: I agree, sense 2 developed from sense 1; it's not clear to me that sense 3 developed from either of those. The OED offers no guidance, but none of the nineteenth century examples of sense 1 or 2 are from American sources; the word doesn't appear to have been in use as anything related to Guy Fawkes in the US in the decades following the Fawkes incident, and then suddenly appears being used to mean "fellow" with entirely benign connotations, contra the usual British usage.

Comment: @1006a That's definitely a reasonable argument.  My line of reasoning for associating all of the senses together was the note you referred to that "the earliest examples" of sense 3 were influenced by sense 2, which made me think that the sense was an outgrowth of those early examples, but that is an assumption on my part, and it's true that the OED offers no explicit guidance.